# goog.Timer.callOnce does not meet formal parameter : Google Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I get the error for formal parameter not matching when using goog.Timer.callOnce even when I think I have declared everything correctly.

```
goog.Timer.callOnce(/** @type {function} */ this.doSomething,0,this);
```

the method definition looks like

```
/**
* @param {!goog.events.Event} e
*/
model.someModel.prototype.doSomething = function(e){
}
```

The error looks like

```
ERROR - actual parameter 1 of goog.Timer.callOnce does not match formal parameter
==> default: [ERROR] found   : function (this:model.someModel, goog.events.Event): undefined
==> default: [ERROR] required: (function (this:model.someModel): ?|null|{handleEvent: function (): ?})
==> default: [ERROR] goog.Timer.callOnce(/** @type {function} */doSomething,0,this);
```

I also tried typecasting `/** @type {function()} */` but even this didnt work

Comment: A couple notes: the compiler won't understand that you're trying to do a typecast unless you  add parentheses: `/** @type {function()} */ (this.doSomething)`. And, `function` is not a type. `!Function` (capital F) means "any function at all" and `function()` means "a function that takes no arguments"

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is expecting a function that takes no arguments (because goog.Timer isn't going to pass any arguments) but you're passing a function that expects one argument. Either change the function so that it doesn't take an argument, or make the argument optional:

```
/**
 * @param {!goog.events.Event=} opt_e
 */
model.someModel.prototype.doSomething = function(opt_e) {
  if (opt_e) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```